# XLS0501 The property 'Content' is set more than once

Tags: xamarin.forms

There is nothing wrong with my code as I can see, but this error I have never seen before keeps coming up, and the Entry element (Input Field) doesn't show up in the UI when I run the app. How to get rid of this problem?

```
<StackLayout>
<Entry
    x:Name="InputField"
    Text="" 
    Placeholder="Enter Todo" 
    TextChanged="HandleTextChanged"
    Completed="HandleCompleted"/>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout x:Name="TodoList">
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: what is the parent of this XAML fragment?

Comment: `ContentPage` can only have a single child element - this also applies to any control with a `Content` property.  If you want to have multiple children, you need to wrap them in a Layout container like a StackLayout, Grid, etc

Comment: The queston needs to provide details on the error the user is getting

Answer (score 0):

As Jason suggested in the comments, The `Content` property of the ContentPage can only accept one direct child element. To get around this, you need to use a `Layout` container, like a `StackLayout` or a `Grid`.

Here's the code sample below for your reference:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry
                 x:Name="InputField"
                 Text="" 
                 Placeholder="Enter Todo" 
                 TextChanged="HandleTextChanged"
                 Completed="HandleCompleted"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="TodoList">
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```